# Restated/simplified: Java generics involving overriding a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a (for me) complex Java generics problem. I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171797/java-generics-involving-inheritance-and-this) in stackoverflow before but came to the conclusion that this example made things overly complex.  So, here the simplified question.

I have two classes as follows

```
abstract public class Base {
     abstract public Base doSomething(Base arg);
}

public class Variant extends Base {
     @Override
     public Variant doSomething(Variant arg) {  // <-- error
           // code
     }
}
```

The error message is "The method doSomething(Variant) of type Variant must override or implement a supertype method."

The selected answer in the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171797/java-generics-involving-inheritance-and-this) is to use generified versions `class Base<T extends Base<T>>` and `class Variant<T extends Variant<T>> extends Base<T>`, which works.  But then, if I want to create an instance of Variant, I need to supply a generics parameter, even though I don't "need" one.

Is there a more simple solution?

Comment: class Variant extends Base<Variant> ?

Comment: The method in `Variant` *doesn't* override the one in `Base` because the argument types aren't the same - it doesn't matter that one is a subtype of the other.

Answer (score 4):

```
abstract public class Base<T extends Base<T>> {
    abstract public T doSomething(T arg);
}

public class Variant extends Base<Variant> {
    @Override
    public Variant doSomething(Variant arg) {  // <-- error
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: sometimes, difficult things are so simple

Answer (score 0):

***No vote please*** If you have function `R f(P)` then an overriden method f' may restrict R to a child, but could only restrict P to a super class whenever f is called.

Computer Science would say: a result type is co-variant, a parameter type is contra-variant (with respect to inheritance).

The solution of making P parametrizable in the base class is correct: @AnatolyDeyneka. For the internal logic R == P.

`doSomething` then not really can be that variable.